# How to make graphs of latitude and longitude and generating summary table

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I am not from geography. I am from quantitative finance. I want a graph with longitude and latitude of various locations of universities of my academic literature. And want to generate a summary table. I am attaching both map and table. I have tried Leaflet library in R and Folium in Python. But not able to generate this kind of map.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So there are a couple of ways to go about this.
In a Python shell, you can use the package 'pandas'. I personally enjoy the ease of using Jupyter Notebook. You can access this by installing anaconda PowerShell and then within the PowerShell type "Jupiter notebook" and it will launch within your working directory. Or, you can use a different software such as Spyder.

You'll first need to import the necessary packages:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
```

You'll then need to read the file. Is your data in the form of CSV or something else? If it is in CSV format you can read it by using:

```
your_data = pd.read_csv(‘C:/.. linktofilename’)
```

To examine your data use,

```
your_data.head()
```

This will print the first 5 rows of your data. If you would like to view more than this just write df.head(50) or the number of rows you would like to view.

You'll then want to assign your latitude and longitude data to variables to make your coding experience easier.

```
lat = your_data['latitude'].values
lon = your_data['longitude'].values
```

You'll then need a basemap. Given the image you provided, it seems you want a world projection? If this is true you can follow the code below. If not, just replace the bounding latlng's with your desired area.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), edgecolor='w')
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution=None,
            llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat=90,
            llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180, )
draw_map(m)
```

You can then project your points as follows:

```
m.scatter(lon, lat, latlon=True,
          cmap='Reds', alpha=0.5)
```

GeoPandas, an extension of Pandas, is also really good for plotting locations. Below are some tutorials that may be helpful:

https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.13-geographic-data-with-basemap.html

https://towardsdatascience.com/geopandas-101-plot-any-data-with-a-latitude-and-longitude-on-a-map-98e01944b972

https://medium.com/@ianforrest11/graphing-latitudes-and-longitudes-on-a-map-bf64d5fca391